# GPU-enabled VM crashes on `import` after attempting to install tensorflow v1.4

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I attempted to

`!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.4` in Colaboratory (GPU-enabled Python 2 instance) and received a "Runtime died. Automatically restarting" error.

After that, any attempt to import modules fails:

`import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import codecs
import pickle 
import time`

...

`Runtime died. Automatically restarting`

How do I fix this? I can no longer run anything, even if I restart the notebook or restart the VM.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that TensorFlow 1.4 built with a different versions of Cuda libraries than those installed in the instance.

I think you can `pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu` and install newer version to make `import tensorflow` work again.

Comment: Yes, this worked! Thank you. I forgot that the CUDA libraries are also a dependency behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Current TF version in Colaboratory is 1.6.0 You should configure the type of runtime environment to GPU.

[image]
After use this feature,

[image]

The execution is transparent:
[image]

If for some reason you need version 1.4.0 Well, sometimes Colaboratory shows a bit weird behavior but the procedure is very simple.
[image]

*If you need py2, same procedure but changing the version of language.

Comment: This is such a thorough response -- thank you! Unfortunately, I was already running on a Python 2 GPU-enabled instance. The issue was in my attempt to force a different Tensorflow version.

Comment: Super @MihirTendulkar! the important thing is that you solved the issue. have a nice day!